# Does iPad development work with interacting through Java code with Spring Framework using TomCat to host the web service on a server? How?

Tags: java, ipad, spring, tomcat

Here is the background of my situation:

I want to create an iPad application that interacts with a oracle SQL database. I have existing Java code from my Flex application that handles all the database requests, and modifications using the Spring Framework. The Flex Application ran as a web service through TomCat. Now I want to make that flex application into a mobile iPad version. I am having trouble figuring out what is the easiest way to use existing Java code and use it for the iPad because the iPad interacts using URL requests instead of direct with the Java.

My question is, can I use the existing Java code with the Spring framework to save time from coding all the back-end handling? Basically I want to access all the classes from my Java code by doing Requests from the iPad. Is this possible and will I need JSON or XML to interact between the iPad and the Java code?

Summary:

Can I use

iPad Objective-C <-----> Java (with spring framework) on TomCat Web Service to handle oracle SQL data handeling? If so, how and what technologies do I need? Will I need JSON or XML and how does that factor between the iPad and Java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach would be to design your app to communicate with RESTful services that return JSON.  Once this is done your iPad app doesn't have to even know that the server code is written in Java.. it's just interacting over HTTP.

Here's a good tutorial on setting up your tomcat to host your RESTful services: http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html  - I've used this for an app I'm developing.  Spring isn't even necessary.

You could go XML, but JSON is just easier in my opinion.  Here's a good blog outlining the good and bad of both sides. http://digitalbazaar.com/2010/11/22/json-vs-xml/

Comment: I say spring because my current java code is using the spring framework and I want to change as little code as possible.

Once I return JSON from the app, what will grab that return and process it through java and then through the database? How does that whole interaction between the return JSON from the iPad app to the database work?

Does it work like this? 
iPad app (JSON) <--> Java <--> Database

Comment: I see your reasoning for sticking with Spring, makes good sense to me. It seems you're on the right track on how the end-to-end interaction works too.  To expand it a little bit more consider: JSON <--> JaxRS(Java) <-- Business Logic (Java) <--> DAO Layer (Java) <--> Database.  JaxRS can handle the JSON in both directions.  It can return it when a GET type request comes in and also receive it when its POSTed and map it to a POJO.  From there, run any relevant business logic on your POJO and interact with the database via a DAO.  Make sense?

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. Finally, is communicating with an iPad app this way really the best way? In my searches, I've seen it mentioned everywhere and that one must avoid direct connection to a database using dependent libraries. Is the http route the best way to communicate with an iPad app?

Now I just have to find some sample code of this SPECIFIC setup to help me get started.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I'm making the following presumptions.

1. Your flex application runs on a different machine from the Tomcat
   server
2. Your flex application makes web service calls to the Tomcat server

So, the flex application doesn't know the underlying technology that provides the web services.  It's just seeing/consuming the output

There's no reason why the iPad app can't do the same thing.  There's no reason why it can't use the same web services that the Flex application uses.  It could consume the same messages (Assuming it can handle the request/response format currently employed by the Flex application).

You can make changes if you like if you want to change the structure of the requests/responses between the clients.  But the clients don't know (nor care) how the web services are implemented.  They are just requesting and consuming info.

Comment: The flex application doesn't interact using a http request and  is deployed by running the TomCat service.

From what I have been searching, for iPad apps, it seems that the best way to interact with a database is by doing HTTP requests, so I am at a lost as to how I can use my existing Java code with the structure to implement it with an iPad app. How can I make an iPad do the same thing when iPad apps and Flex Applications has different interaction structures?

Comment: The flex application is on the same machine as the TomCat service and is deployed by the TomCat service. Clients use the Flex Application by visitng a URL that is set up through TomCat and the server its on. I don't think we can say iPad and Flex can do the same thing as an iPad app is hosted on the iPad not a server.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the original question.  Yes, a web server supplies a flex application (which runs in the browser).  I also thought you had Java code which implemented web services in the Server that was used by the Flex code (in the browser).  I wasn't aware that Flex applications used Java class files, so I presumed any Java code was not in the Flex application itself, but instead in the Tomcat server in a 2-tier architecture. Can you elaborate on the  communication method between the existing Flex client and the Java services?

Comment: And I wasn't suggesting that flex be run on the iPad.  The iPad app will still need to be written.  It's just that they could use the same remote services that are currently servicing the Flex application (assuming they are remote services).